# Go server not hearing remote requests

Tags: go

I've written a Go server that works perfectly as long as you send it requests from localhost (and addressed to localhost), but it doesn't work when you try to access it from a browser (from a different computer) or even just directed at the external IP address. I want to be able to access it as an external server, not just locally. Why can't it?

The (pared down) source code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Listen for incoming connections.
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:2082")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        _, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Println("Incoming connection")
    }
}
```

When you `curl localhost:2082`, it says "Incoming connection".
When you `curl mydomain.com:2082`, it does nothing.

The port **is forwarded**. I'm sure of this because I ran a (node.js) web server from that port, and it worked fine. If it's related, I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with `net.Listen("tcp", ":2082")`?

Comment: Please answer this question so I can mark your answer as correct! Also, why does this change anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to listen to any incoming IP (not just `localhost`, mapped by default to 127.0.0.1) would be:

```
net.Listen("tcp", ":2082")
```

You also have the function [`net/http/#ListenAndServe`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe), which allows you to [trigger listen on multiple specific ip if you want](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/LHkUszUmjGI).

```
go http.ListenAndServe("10.0.0.1:80", nil)
http.ListenAndServe("10.0.0.2:80", nil)
```

A good example can be seen in "[A Recap of Request Handling in Go](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/a-recap-of-request-handling)".

Comment: Just to add a little bit of info, "localhost" is usually mapped to the ip 127.0.0.1, which is well, your local address, so only local clients can connect to it.