# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it Golang

Tags: http, go, websocket, server

I have server:

```
func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:12345")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error during Accept")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        _, err = ws.Upgrade(conn)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error during Upgrade")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        go func() {
           some code
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

and client, which trying to connect to my computer:

```
func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    payload := []byte("Hello World!")

    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error during writing into Binary")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "37.57.79.119:12345")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error during Dialing")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    buf.WriteTo(conn)
    defer conn.Close()

    answer, _ := io.ReadAll(conn)
    fmt.Println(string(answer))
}
```

My system is Kubuntu 20.04, I compiling client for windows, and send it to my friend. On friend machine, he launches it, and receives error:

```
Error during Dialing
dial tcp 37.57.79.119:12345: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Why? My Firewall is off.

Comment: Of course, server is online, when client launches, and port 12345 is open (I checked it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:12345")` is listening on `localhost` and client is trying to connect by IP.

Try connecting client on `localhost`

```
net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:12345")
```

Or listen the server on `0.0.0.0`

```
net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:12345")
```

Comment: But client launches in another PC, in other city. How this would help?

Comment: If you listen on `localhost:12345` then only local (i.e. on your computer) apps will be able to connect (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24843995/11810946)). Listen on `0.0.0.0:12345` (or, just `:12345`) to allow external access. Note that none of this will work unless your computer has a publicly accessible IP address (unlikely) or you have configured a port forward on your router.